# Tips on how to find Vout

Tags: operational-amplifier

Could someone please give me some hints/point me in the right direction as to how to find Vout for the circuit below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the voltage on the opamp's non-inverting input in a straightforward way, then use your knowledge of the rest of the configuration to relate VOUT to that.

Comment: @ jp314 Could you please tell if this is right: V(+)= V(in) * R/(R-jXc) and Xc=1/(wc) .

Comment: it is correct. Standard notation is Xc = 1/(jwC), which is also                -j/(wC)